# Differences regarding neo4j and mySQL

Tags: mysql, neo4j

I have to develop a project for college regarding databases. I have to basically develop the same project in a relational database like mySQL and in a non-relational database like neo4j. I'm pretty versed in mySQL but there is something in node4j that i don't understand.
While in mySQL i can just write this:

```
CREATE_TABLE 'A' (
 'idA' INT not NULL
)
```

and this will create a table that has a column named idA and i may add rows to the table for specific values.
From what i've understood so far, in neo4j i can't really create something ambiguous like this? Every node or label that i create, has to have specific values for the properties i assigned to it. Is this correct? or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The analogue to your empty table example is literally a label (e.g. A) for which there are no nodes.

If you wanted to ensure that the attribute `idA` existed on every `A` table node that is created in your database you could create a constraint on the label `A` something like this.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:A) ASSERT exists(a.idA)
```